# can't install cordova using npm install -g cordova

Tags: node.js, cordova

npm ERR! Darwin 15.6.0

npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "cordova"

npm ERR! node v4.6.0

npm ERR! npm  v2.15.9

npm ERR! code ENOTFOUND

npm ERR! errno ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! syscall getaddrinfo

npm ERR! network getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND proxy.company.com proxy.company.com:8080

npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself

npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.

npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.

npm ERR! network

npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the

npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:

npm ERR!     /Users/admin/npm-debug.log

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Please help me ,THX a lot , I try npm cache clean , but not work, thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running the following command first

`npm config delete proxy`

Comment: OH yeah, I try this script "sudo chmod -R 777 /usr/local/"   it works!!!!!!!!!!!!!