# Cannot install Apache Cordova using "npm install -g cordova"

Tags: android, windows, cordova

all. I've been trying to install Apache Cordova on my Windows 10 PC, and I've been getting this issue over and over. I've been following these three guides to install Cordova:
cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/index.html

evothings.com/doc/build/cordova-install-windows.html

www.tutorialspoint.com/cordova/cordova_environment_setup.htm

I checked on the command line and Git, Android Studio and the JDK have all been installed successfully like the tutorials asked for and I took a look at some similar posts here on SO where the answer was to use "sudo npm install -g cordova" as well as [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40066593/cant-install-cordova-using-npm-install-g-cordova) and no luck.
And here's the error I've been getting :

```
 npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: EBUSY: resource    busy or locked, rename 'C:\Users\Ray\AppData\Local\Temp\npm-7756-015c0ec3 \registry.npmjs.org\path-parse\-\path-parse-1.0.5.tgz.2712739132' -> 'C:\Users\Ray\AppData\Local\Temp\npm-7756-015c0ec3\registry.npmjs.org\path-parse\-\path-parse-1.0.5.tgz'
 npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
 npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program   Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "cordova"
npm ERR! node v6.10.3
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10

npm ERR! tarball.destroy is not a function
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: EBUSY: resource  busy or locked, rename 'C:\Users\Ray\AppData\Local\Temp\npm-7756-015c0ec3\registry.npmjs.org\tty-browserify\-\tty-browserify-0.0.0.tgz.1810143622' -> 'C:\Users\Ray\AppData\Local\Temp\npm-7756-015c0ec3\registry.npmjs.org\tty-browserify\-\tty-browserify-0.0.0.tgz'
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "cordova"
npm ERR! node v6.10.3
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10

npm ERR! tarball.destroy is not a function
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, rename 'C:\Users\Ray\AppData\Local\Temp\npm-7756-015c0ec3\registry.npmjs.org\tty-browserify\-\tty-browserify-0.0.0.tgz.709475096' -> 'C:\Users\Ray\AppData\Local\Temp\npm-7756-015c0ec3\registry.npmjs.org\tty-browserify\-\tty-browserify-0.0.0.tgz'
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "cordova"
npm ERR! node v6.10.3
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10

npm ERR! tarball.destroy is not a function
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
```

Comment: Welcome to OS ! First rule to publish your question: Don't put your log in a screenshot. Please update your question and put the log inside the code brackets !

Comment: Done. My appologies.

Comment: Did u install node latest version first ? & after installing the node u need to enter  npm install -g cordova in command line

Comment: Yes, it was done on the command line that comes with node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe some anti-virus software running in the system could be causing this issue. Try stopping the anti-virus program and install cordova.

An other probable fix for this issue could be to install latest version of nodejs.

Comment: This doesn't but I am open to the idea that it's some program preventing cordova from installing.

Comment: I digress, it was some anti-virus that I wasn't even aware was installed on my PC. Cheers.

Comment: @AlphaNull please accept and upvote the answer if it helped... Cheers

Comment: I accepted the answer but as a brand new user I cannnot upvote yet. Cheers once again.